# How to output a char to the console without moving the cursor afterwards in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

I am currently using C# (.NET 4.5) to craft a console application. The problem I have is that the cursor always moves to the next cell after using Console.Write(char c), so when it reaches the last cell of a line, it goes to the next line, messing up all the layout. Is it possible to output a char to the console (with background and foreground color) without moving the cursor afterwards?

The code I am using is the following:

```
Console.BackgroundColor = bgColor;
Console.ForegroundColor = fgColor;
Console.SetCursorPosition(currX, currY);
Console.Write(c);
```

Assume currX and currY as integers, bgColor and fgColor as ConsoleColor and c as a char.

Thankyou.

Comment: You need to be more specific about how you use `SetCursorPosition` as that's clearly the issue here. You should be able to print and simply back up the cursor position by 1 character and be good to go.

Comment: Somewhat awkwardly, you can "write" to the bottom right position without having the page scroll using the [MoveBufferArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.movebufferarea(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

Comment: I use SetCursorPosition to write to a specific cell. The problem is that if I write to the position 79 of a line, it goes to the next one. I think that the problem is that I should be using something else that is not Console.Write, but I don't know what. I have also checked MSDN and nothing comes up.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, do you suggest using MoveBufferArea instead of Write with a one-cell area?

Comment: You can reset the position again using SetCursorPosition after doing Console.Write(c).

Comment: @Studiosi: Yes. Write out the character e.g. to the first position, then move it into place. Obviously, you will have to write out the real first position character after doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation of the `Console` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx#Buffer), it provides access only to the standard output stream, not to the screen buffer (although you can change some properties of the buffer, such as its size).  And `MoveBufferArea` is another obvious exception, but doesn't really apply here<sup>1</sup>.

The Win32 API does provide access to the console buffer.  You would probably want to p/invoke [`WriteConsoleOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`WriteConsoleOutputCharacter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687410%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  (p/invoke declarations [here](http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=WriteConsoleOutput&namespace=%5bAll%5d))

Notably:

> `WriteConsoleOutput` has no effect on the cursor position.

Oh, you'll probably want the Unicode versions (ending in `W`) because .NET strings are all UTF-16.

---

<sup>1</sup> It lets you provide content two ways: content already in the buffer -- but getting it there in the first place is the problem, or from a character and attribute provided -- but this is only used to fill the "source" area, and the destination is not optional.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like...

```
Console.Write("b");
Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);
Console.Write("c");
```

For me, this just prints prints `b`, then replaces it with `c`. Effectively, the first two lines together write to the console without moving the cursor. You can conclude this because when you write `c`, it overwrites the `b` rather than placing it at the next position.

You could even write a helper method:

```
static void WriteWithoutMove(string s) 
{
    Console.Write(s);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: It's not quite that simple. If he writes a character at the end of a line, the cursor is going to move down to the next line. And if he writes to the last position of the last line in the console window, the window will scroll.

Comment: @JimMischel That's a good thought. OP will need to keep track of the last position written to each time something is written and re-set the position to that previous position when he wants to write without move.

Comment: I will try both this solution and the buffer solution. I will update when I have time to try it.

Comment: This solution can't be made to work because you can't prevent the scrolling when a character is written to the last column on the last line.

Comment: This is overthinking it a lot. Just save the old cursor position, do whatever you want, then restore the old position. No need to care about buffer width etc.

Comment: @AnorZaken I dont think that will work. Say your buffer size is set to 10x10. If the caret is on position 10,10, writing a single char to the console will throw an exception. Likewise, say the window size is 10x10 and the buffer is something greater. Writing a single char to the console at position 10,10 will the console to be scrolled down, because the caret's new position exceeds the window size

Comment: @devklick I'm not sure I understand you, I'm not the one writing to the console, my code is supposed to move the cursor back to where it was - if the problem lies with the write itself, then that is a different issue. If you need to change the buffer content without triggering the automatic cursor move, as opposed to trying to correct the cursor position afterwards as is discussed here, then unfortunately you have to go OS-level and access a Win32 api. When using the Console class the defualt way you do not have direct access to the underlying buffer (as far as I recall).

Comment: That limitation _does_ indeed mean that you cannot write to the last visible position, as that would cause a new-line that pushes all of the visible content upwards one row. I saw that as beyond the scope of a comment. But yes, you do need to keep both buffer and window size in mind when writing code for this stuff (unless you want to access the underlying buffer via OS).

Answer (score 1):

I remember the old DOS, with the OLD command (for example) BASIC:

```
locate(21,50)
print "Qty[26]";
```

Note:
The (`;`) use for stick the cursor for the text and add 1 char, if you use the (`,`) is `TAB (CHR$(8))`